# Как получить ник пользователя через его id в telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Я Использую следующую функцию для получения сообщений из чатов (это библиотека telethon)

```
async def dump_all_messages(channel) -> list:
    '''функция для сбора сообщений с канала'''
    offset_msg = 0    # номер записи, с которой начинается считывание
    limit_msg = 100   # максимальное число записей, передаваемых за один раз

    all_messages = []   # список всех сообщений
    total_messages = 0
    total_count_limit = 0

    while True:
        history = await telethon_client(GetHistoryRequest(
            peer=channel,
            offset_id=offset_msg,
            offset_date=None, add_offset=0,
            limit=limit_msg, max_id=0, min_id=0,
            hash=0))
        if not history.messages:
            break
        messages = history.messages
        for message in messages:
            message = message.to_dict()
            all_messages.append({message['from_id']: message['message'].replace('\n', ' ').replace(r'\u', ' ')}): 
        offset_msg = messages[len(messages) - 1].id
        total_messages = len(all_messages)
        if total_count_limit != 0 and total_messages >= total_count_limit:
            break
    return all_messages
```

Проблема заключается в том, что эта функция возвращает id отправителей, а мне нужны ники. Но я не могу найти функцию для ***обычного*** API (я не использую бот-api) которая позволила бы по id юзера получить его ник. Я пробовал

```
filter_user = ChannelParticipantsSearch('')

    while True:
        participants = await telethon_client(GetParticipantsRequest(channel,
                                                                    filter_user, offset_user, limit_user, hash=0))
```

где в качестве фильтра берётся строка т.е. не id а ник. Так же я пробовал метод библиотеки pyrogram

```
with Client('user', api, 'hash') as app:
            user = app.get_users('username')
            name = user.username
            return name
```

Но она тоже требует ник а не id. Как мне получить ник человека в телеграме по его id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [get_entity()](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.users.UserMethods.get_entity), ему на вход можно передать [почти что угодно](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/entities.html#getting-entities):

`user = await client.get_entity(1234567)`