# Как получить никнейм человека из его айди

Tags: python, telebot, telegram

У меня есть список людей по их айди но нет их ников/имён
Мне нужно только из айди получить их ники (У меня нет их сообщений)

```
import os
import telebot
bot = telebot # Эта строчка не важна

def wishlist(message,sender):
    file = open(f"users\\{sender.id}\\wishlist.txt", "r")
    wishlists = int(file.readline())
    file.close()

    if wishlists > 0:
        file = open(f"users\\{sender.id}\\wishlist.txt", "w")
        file.write(str(wishlists - 1))
        file.close()
        
        leaders = leaderstats(message,sender)
        
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{leaders}')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'')

def leaderstats(message,sender):
    userslist = ""
    for user in os.listdir("users\\"):
        file = open(f"users\\{user}\\balance.txt", "r")
        balance = file.readline()
        file.close()

        userName = # Здесь нужно получить ник человека из его айди

        userslist = userslist + f"{userName}: {balance}{currency}\n"
    
    print(userslist)
    return userslist
```

Comment: Попробуйте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1173888/Как-получить-ник-пользователя-через-его-id-в-telegram).

Comment: В telebot нет этой функции